# Wordpress - Pass function arguments when adding menu page

Tags: wordpress, oop, plugins, menu

In WordPress I'm adding a new menu page like this:

```
 add_menu_page(
      'Page Name',
      'Page Name',
      'manage_options',
      'page-name',
      array($this, 'page_function')
 );
```

However, I want to pass some arguments when running the function page_function. Ideally, it would be something like this (but doesn't work):

```
 add_menu_page(
      'Page Name',
      'Page Name',
      'manage_options',
      'page-name',
      array($this, 'page_function("arg1", "arg2")')
 );
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can do this using an anonymous function. See this answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107729/68917

Answer (score 2):

In that context, you can't. The callback accepts only one parameter. You can, however, do something like:

```
<?php
function page_function($file) {
    // logic here to set parameters $arg1 and $arg2
    page_function_helper( $file, 1, 2 );
}

function page_function_helper($file, $arg1, $arg2) {
    // do whatever you need to do
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure how that doesn't (didn't) work -- what was the different solution that you came across?